# Error importing numpy from Flask into Heroku application

Tags: python, numpy, heroku, flask

I am using Heroku to deploy my Flask application.

Inside my application I am trying to import numpy. This works fine on my localhost, however when I deploy to Heroku the build never completes.

When I check my Heroku logs it is clear that it cannot find numpy.

I have tried putting numpy into my requirments.txt with different version numbers but none seems to work.

I've also tried adding a buildpack which includes numpy, following an example on like this: https://github.com/kennethreitz/conda-buildpack

On the official Heroku python build pack it says: "Some Python packages with obscure C dependencies (e.g. scipy) are not compatible"

Is it possible to import numpy somehow though?

Comment: Check the `numpy` dependencies, and include all of them in your `requirements.txt` as well?

Comment: Ah yea, I did not think to check the numpy dependencies... will look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert on heroku, but installing numpy requires compiling of c dependencies and stuff like that. And to be able to do that, the system running your application needs dev packages. Such as python-dev.

In heroku docs is [advice](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-c-deps) to use custom [buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) to support obscure c dependencies. I've found this [buildpack that should support numpy and scipy](https://github.com/thenovices/heroku-buildpack-scipy).

I hope this will work for you.

Cheers!